# Using custom UITextField in UITextFieldDelegate functions

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to create a custom UI Text field in Swift. Here is my code

```
public class AmountTextField : UITextField{

    let currencyFormattor = NSNumberFormatter()

    let amountTextFieldDelegate = AmountTextFieldDelegate()

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initTextField()
    }

    func initTextField(){
        self.delegate = amountTextFieldDelegate
        currencyFormattor.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormattor.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        currencyFormattor.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    }

    func setAmount (amount : Double){
        let textFieldStringValue = currencyFormattor.stringFromNumber(amount)
        self.text = textFieldStringValue
    } 
}
```

And my AmountTextFieldDelegate looks like this

```
class AmountTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textField(textField: AmountTextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let amount = getAmount() // calculates the amount
        textField.setAmount(amount)

        return false
    }
}
```

I changed UITextField to AmountTextField in shouldChangeCharactersInRange so that I could call the setAmount function in shouldChangeCharactersInRange. But when I do that, I get the error -

Objective-C method 'textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:' provided by method 'textField(*:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'textField(*:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)' in protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'

Is there a way I can call the setAmount in shouldChangeCharactersInRange?

Comment: what does set amount do? you are trying to override a method that already exists in the delegate

Comment: No, just formats the amount and adds it to the text field. I added that pice of code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class AmountTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let s = textField as? AmountTextField {
            let amount = s.getAmount() // calculates the amount
            s.setAmount(amount)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: @Richa Actually I am still wondering why you version does not work. I'll try to log a bug to Swift community. Let see what do they reply.

Comment: I was wondering too, I feel like I have done this in Objective C

Comment: Yep, Obj-C equivalent compiles fine